# Multiple Queries With Try Catch and Transact statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to execute two distinct queries as a unit sing the transaction
i describe the tables below :

members table

```
| member_id | name |
```

members_groups table

```
| id | member_id | group_id |
```

groups table

```
| group_id | group_name |
```

the members_groups contains two foreign key from the other two tables

below is the code

```html
try{  
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `members_groups` WHERE member_id = ?");
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `members` WHERE member_id = ?");

    $stmt->bindParam(1,$id , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->bindParam(1,$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);      

    if($stmt->execute() && $stmt2->execute()) {
        $dbh->commit(); 
        echo "registered successfully";    
    }
}
catch (Exception $e){
    $dbh->rollback();
    echo "an error has occurred";
}
```

I want to delete a row from the members table but first I have to delete the child key from the members_groups table.
when I run the sql queries in the phpmyadmin console the two queries run successfully 
but when I run the queries with the php pdo nothing happens.

Comment: What does your script output?

Comment: the query does not output an error message

Comment: Did you set PDO in [exception mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)?

Comment: this is what I have  ----  try{
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=datacentre', USER, PASSWORD, array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
 //echo 'Connected to database';

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL  "  . $e);
    exit();
}

Comment: after using this code $stmt->errorCode()  , I get a error of 42000. Any help